# My Ubuntu 18.04.1 laptop freezes an hour or so after resuming from sleep

Tags: 18.04, suspend, freeze

My HP ZBook15 (Intel i5-4310M x4, graphics Intel Haswell Mobile) randomly freezes after resuming from suspend (also hibernate but let's keep it simple), after maybe 30 mins or a couple of hours. Screen stays intact, clock freezes, and mouse (touchpad) may or may not move. 
Ctl-Alt-Del does nothing, unsure of Caps or Num Lock toggle.
I have Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, Gnome 3.28.2, and a whole bunch of developer tools.
I have a non-HP-supplied 2TB HDD drive and no SSD.
I can supply more info if someone asks, and tells me how to get it.

Comment: After resuming after sleeping (and no freeze), another sleep (done by closing lid) ... doesn't sleep. It goes into a strange twilight zone - power on, WiFi on, screen black probably . When THAT is 'resumed' (lid opened), after a second or so from black, it displays a log-on screen that required a swipe-up. On swipe-up, it freezes for 20 seconds (ToD shows seconds) with no CapsLock or NumLock toggle possible, then carries on as though nothing is unusual.